# Adding owner indication for "edited" entry in timeline

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, timeline, owner

In the timeline view, for the `comment` entries, if it is added by the owner, we can see some background color to differentiate from other user's comment entries.

But the identification of owner is not added for the `history` entries, especially for the **edited**. Since a post can be edited by many users, we required the owner indication for the edited too.

Please find a sample [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/340697/timeline?filter=NoVoteDetail) and screen shot for reference:

> [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

History entries on the timeline created by the post owner are now styled with the same highlight around the name of the owner on that row, as is done for comments made by the owner.