# When a user offers a bounty on their own question, their name isn't highlighted

Tags: bug, design, bounties, timeline

All the bounty events (bounty started, notice added, bounty ended, notice removed) are missing the blue highlight (exact color varies by theme) for the OP's name in the timeline. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72509513/timeline):

[image: "nick" places a bounty]

([More examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/220/promoter).)

I found this confusing, so can it be changed?

Comment: Related: [OP name not highlighted in reopen action in timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369211/op-name-not-highlighted-in-reopen-action-in-timeline)

Comment: Along with: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348371/282094  
related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369211/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347540/282094