# "bounty start" with reputation entry is removed from the bounty post's timeline

Tags: bug, reputation, bounties, timeline

When there is a bounty added for a question, previously there are three entries are added to the post's timeline, such as :

- "bounty started"
- "notice added" with a comment provided by the person who initiated the bounty
- "bounty start" with the bounty reputation

Screenshot from one of an old [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342574/312043), which has the "bounty start" entry with the reputation, circled in red.

> [image: bounty start removed]

But in recent times the "bounty start" with reputation entry is removed from the bounty post's timeline.

The entry contains the detail about the bounty reward reputation, it will help in the future to know how much reputation was allocated as a bounty for the post in the timeline.

The "bounty start" entry is not available in the recent [bounty questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Bounties) timeline.

Comment: It'd be useful to have a link to a post with a bounty on it.

Comment: It seems to have been moved to the revisions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/346483/revisions some time after 2020: [In the timeline, should the start of a bounty by the OP also be considered a change to the question by the OP?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348371/282094)

Comment: The API shows the amount of the bounty in the [revisions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#ids=346483&filter=default&site=meta) and not in the [timeline](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-timeline#ids=346483&filter=default&site=meta&run=true) too.

Comment: FYA, the bug report is still not clear and appears to contain lots of non relevant noise that makes it hard to understand what the real bug is, if there is any.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Are you able to see the *reputation* provided for the bounty question in the question's timeline?

Comment: OK, I might try and edit it into shape if I'll have time. Like I said, the major issue is non relevant noise included in the report.